# Get value from javascript to jsp tags

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have got a script:

```
function onAjaxNewOrderCountReceived() {
    // process data
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
       if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           var strOrderCount = xmlhttp.responseText;

           var orderCount = parseInt(strOrderCount.replace('"',''));
           $("#new-order-count").html(orderCount);
       } else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
          alert('There was an error 400');
       } else {
           alert('Error!! HTTP Code ' + xmlhttp.status + ' was returned! Unable to get count of new orders.');
       }
    }
}
```

I want to get the value orderCount in my jsp page. Here is the code in jsp:

```
<form action="orderdashboard" method="post">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-fit-height btn-danger searchOrder">
        <strong class="new-order-count" id="new-order-count"></strong> 
        NEW ORDERS <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

Problem is, I'm not getting the value that is to be displayed inside the  tag. Please help.

Comment: You should be having an input element so that form value could be retrieved by your server side language...

Comment: More precisely, add `<input type="text" name="passedValue">Text field</input>` and
`<input type="submit" value="Submit" />` and then you can retrieve the passed value with `request.getParameter("passedValue");`